# Chrome Extension: Inject content_scripts into blob:chrome-extension:// URL

Tags: google-chrome-extension, content-script, bloburls

**Problem**

Example:

Create a html file and convert it to string format.

Update new tab while using blob object to create URL.

```
const blob = new Blob([`<html></html>`], { type: "text/html" });
await chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, { url: URL.createObjectURL(blob) });
```

manifest.json:

```
"content_scripts":[{
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["test.js"],
            "all_frames": true,
            "match_origin_as_fallback": true,
            "run_at": "document_idle"
}]
```

**Question**
Is it possible to inject content script to the url such like blob:chrome-extension://... ?

Comment: I tried it just now and it didn't inject .
By the way, chrome-extension://... is the same.

Comment: Blobs are tied to their origin, which makes this page a subset of chrome-extension:// origin, which doesn't support content scripts by design. Try adding `<script src=foo.js>` elements inside the string you use to construct the blob.

Comment: @wOxxOm I tried something like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js" />`, but it just add this string to it but don't know where is test.js.

Comment: @wOxxOm Also, I tried `<script type="text/javascript" src={chrome.runtime.getURL("test.js")} />`, and it just get error with Refused to load the script 'chrome-extension://demicjpchoggkpifjlokcafdfmloppfi/test.js'

Comment: Apparently blobs can't load extension's scripts. There's probably no solution, so you may have to abandon the idea of creating the page via a blob. Just do it via normal DOM methods e.g. open page.html from your extension, send the data to it, so the page can change itself.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is it possible to add contentScript to url that start with chrome-extension:// (some html file in my extension)

Comment: No, not possible.